# Compiler: "instantiated object" does not name a type

Tags: c++, winapi, win32gui

I'm having a problem with creating a WIN32 GUI application in C++ (I'm used Code::Blocks to auto-generate the main.cpp). Here's the header file I made for a class that paints objects to the screen.

```
#ifndef CANVAS_H
#define CANVAS_H
#include <windows.h>

class Point{
private:
    const double default_x = 0.0, default_y = 0.0;
public:
    double x, y;
    Point();
    Point(const Point& rval);
    Point(double x, double y);
    bool operator==(const Point& rval);
    Point& operator=(const Point& rval);
    Point distanceAway(double x, double y);
};

class GraphicObject{
private:
    int size;
    Point offset;
    Point* points;
public:
    GraphicObject();
    GraphicObject(const GraphicObject& rval);
    void paint(HWND& hwnd, HDC hdc);
    void addPoint(const Point& p);
    //void removePoint(const Point& p);
};
#endif
```

And here's the implementation:

```
#include "Canvas.h"
#include <windows.h>

//Point Class Definitions
//Default constructor
Point::Point(): x(default_x), y(default_y){}
//Copy constructor
Point::Point(const Point& rval): x(rval.x), y(rval.y){}
//Constructor
Point::Point(double x, double y): x(x), y(y){}
//Equality operator
bool Point::operator==(const Point& rval){ return (x == rval.x && y == rval.y); }
//Assignment operator
Point& Point::operator=(const Point& rval){
x = rval.x;
y = rval.y;
return *this;
}
//Function to find point certain distance away from calling object
Point Point::distanceAway(double x, double y){ return Point(this->x + x, this->y + y); }

//GraphicObject Class Definitions
//Default constructor (makes a triangle)
GraphicObject::GraphicObject(){
points = new Point[(size = 0)];
offset = Point(50,50);
}
//Copy constructor
GraphicObject::GraphicObject(const GraphicObject& rval){
delete[] points;
points = new Point[(size = rval.size)];
for(int i=0; i<size; i++){ points[i] = rval.points[i]; }
}
//Function to paint to screen
void GraphicObject::paint(HWND& hwnd, HDC hdc){
hdc = GetDC(hwnd);
for(int i=0; i<(size - 1); i++){
    MoveToEx(hdc, points[i].x + offset.x, points[i].y + offset.y, NULL);
    LineTo(hdc, points[i + 1].x + offset.x, points[i + 1].y + offset.y);
}
MoveToEx(hdc, points[size - 1].x + offset.x, points[size - 1].y + offset.y, NULL);
LineTo(hdc, points[0].x + offset.x, points[0].y + offset.y);

ReleaseDC(hwnd, hdc);
}
//Function to add points to shape
void GraphicObject::addPoint(const Point& p){
Point* temp = new Point[size];//DYNAMIC MEMORY temp ALLOCATED
for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
    temp[i] = points[i];
}
delete[] points;
points = new Point[++size];
for(int i=0; i<(size - 1); i++){ points[i] = temp[i]; }
delete[] temp;//DYNAMIC MEMORY temp DELETED
points[size - 1] = p;
}
```

In the main.cpp the compiler finds an error at the line right after I instantiate an object of class GraphicObject.

```
#if defined(UNICODE) && !defined(_UNICODE)
#define _UNICODE
#elif defined(_UNICODE) && !defined(UNICODE)
#define UNICODE
#endif

#include <tchar.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include "Canvas.h"

/*  Declare Windows procedure  */
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure (HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

/*  Make the class name into a global variable  */
TCHAR szClassName[ ] = _T("CodeBlocksWindowsApp");

int WINAPI WinMain (HINSTANCE hThisInstance,
                 HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                 LPSTR lpszArgument,
                 int nCmdShow)
{
HWND hwnd;               /* This is the handle for our window */
MSG messages;            /* Here messages to the application are saved */
WNDCLASSEX wincl;        /* Data structure for the windowclass */

/* The Window structure */
wincl.hInstance = hThisInstance;
wincl.lpszClassName = szClassName;
wincl.lpfnWndProc = WindowProcedure;      /* This function is called by windows */
wincl.style = CS_DBLCLKS;                 /* Catch double-clicks */
wincl.cbSize = sizeof (WNDCLASSEX);

/* Use default icon and mouse-pointer */
wincl.hIcon = LoadIcon (NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
wincl.hIconSm = LoadIcon (NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
wincl.hCursor = LoadCursor (NULL, IDC_ARROW);
wincl.lpszMenuName = NULL;                 /* No menu */
wincl.cbClsExtra = 0;                      /* No extra bytes after the window class */
wincl.cbWndExtra = 0;                      /* structure or the window instance */
/* Use Windows's default colour as the background of the window */
wincl.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH) COLOR_BACKGROUND;

/* Register the window class, and if it fails quit the program */
if (!RegisterClassEx (&wincl))
    return 0;

/* The class is registered, let's create the program*/
hwnd = CreateWindowEx (
       0,                   /* Extended possibilites for variation */
       szClassName,         /* Classname */
       _T("Code::Blocks Template Windows App"),       /* Title Text */
       WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, /* default window */
       CW_USEDEFAULT,       /* Windows decides the position */
       CW_USEDEFAULT,       /* where the window ends up on the screen */
       544,                 /* The programs width */
       375,                 /* and height in pixels */
       HWND_DESKTOP,        /* The window is a child-window to desktop */
       NULL,                /* No menu */
       hThisInstance,       /* Program Instance handler */
       NULL                 /* No Window Creation data */
       );

/* Make the window visible on the screen */
ShowWindow (hwnd, nCmdShow);

/* Run the message loop. It will run until GetMessage() returns 0 */
while (GetMessage (&messages, NULL, 0, 0))
{
    /* Translate virtual-key messages into character messages */
    TranslateMessage(&messages);
    /* Send message to WindowProcedure */
    DispatchMessage(&messages);
}

/* The program return-value is 0 - The value that PostQuitMessage() gave */
return messages.wParam;
}

int x = 0, y = 10;
GraphicObject g;
g.addPoint(Point());

/*  This function is called by the Windows function DispatchMessage()  */

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure (HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
PAINTSTRUCT ps;
HDC hdc;
switch (message)                  /* handle the messages */
{
    case WM_PAINT:
        //x++;
        //hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
        //hdc = GetDC(hwnd);
        //Rectangle(hdc, 0, 0, 544, 375);
        //TextOut(hdc, x, y, "MOVING TEXT WOO!", strlen("MOVING TEXT WOO!"));
        //ReleaseDC(hwnd, hdc);
        //EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
        g.paint(hwnd, hdc);
        std::cout << "Window repainted\n";
        Sleep(5);
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage (0);       /* send a WM_QUIT to the message queue */
        break;
    default:                      /* for messages that we don't deal with */
        return DefWindowProc (hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
        InvalidateRect(hwnd, NULL, true);
        UpdateWindow(hwnd);
}
return 0;
}
```

Specifically, this line is where I have the problem:

```
g.addPoint(Point());
```

Comment: This code is _huge_. Where is your testcase?

Comment: If you'd properly indent your code, you'd see where the problem lies very easily.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to have a statement which is not a declaration at namespace scope. This is prohibited: statements other than declaration statements can only appear within a function body.

To apply operations to an object at namespace scope without being in a function, i.e., during initialization, you can utilize a constructor of an auxiliary object, e.g.:

```
GraphicObject g;
namespace {
    struct g_init {
        g_init() { g.addPoint(Point()); }
    } init;
}
```

If the type `GraphicObject` is copyable/movable it may be easier to initialize the object using a function call, though:

```
namespace {
    GraphicObject g_init() {
        GraphicObject g;
        g.addPoint(Point());
    }
}
GraphicObject g = g_init();
```